# does one point sets are closed in a non hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

What is the actual meaning of

> one point sets are closed

Is it true if space is not Hausdorff?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If a space is Hausdorff then singletons are closed. If singletons are closed then a space gets the label $T_1$, but it is not necessarily Hausdorff.

Comment: @Shaun: What good is a MathJax tutorial for a question that doesn't contain any formulas?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It looked like the user was trying to type some formulae, that's all. I thought I'd share the tutorial. There's no harm in it :)

Answer (score 1):

One point sets are closed means for any $x\in X$, $X\setminus\{x\}$ is in the topology i.e. open.

This is of course not true in general. Take $X=\{0,1\}$ and the trivial topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another example is the cofinite topology over an infinite set to show it is not true.

Comment: One point sets are closed in the cofinite topology.

Comment: One point sets are closed but the space is not Hausdorff.